# SAP_HANA) How to apply 'Client Code Page' option when connect to ODBC on Linux

Tags: odbc, connection-string, hana

When I run a SQL statement containing UTF8 characters, DB does not seem to recognize the character Encoding.
When accessing SAP_HANA DB with ODBC, I want to pass the Code page to the factor together, but there is no example of how to use the option.

Currently, the connection string except for the Code page option in C++ code is as follows.

```
connectString =
    "driver={HDBODBC};UID=" + userId +  
    ";PWD=" + password + 
    ";serverNode=" + serverNode +
    ";DATABASENAME=" + databaseName + 
    ";CHAR_AS_UTF8=true";
```

How do I add it here to use the Codepage option?

I think it's as below, but it's uncertain.

```
connectString =
    "driver={HDBODBC};UID=" + userId +  
    ";PWD=" + password + 
    ";serverNode=" + serverNode +
    ";DATABASENAME=" + databaseName + 
    ";CHAR_AS_UTF8=true" +
    ";ClientCodePage=65001;
```

---

### additional question

If Korean is included in the query as shown below
The column name returns normally, but the value returns abnormally.

In this case, applying the CHAR_AS_UTF8 option to false allows you to include Korean in the SQL statement, but you cannot obtain Korean data.

SQL : SELECT '한글' FROM DUMMY;

JDBC = '한글'
한글

ODBC = '한글'
í��ê¸�

Here's the problem. If you write Korean as a condition, the query runs normally, but you cannot get Korean data because CHAR_AS_UTF8 is false.

How can we take action?

SQL : SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE col1 = '한글';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAP HANA ODBC driver does not provide automatic character set conversion for non-Unicode character sets. (see https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/7cab593774474f2f8db335710b2f5c50.html - there is no option for that).

Instead, the application has to know how to interpret the codes stored in the database, if it indeed uses a non-Unicode encoding.

From a HANA point of view, all strings are unicode strings, even if declared as `VARCHAR`, `CHAR`, or `CLOB` (instead of `NVARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, or `NCLOB`).